# ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle cannot be used together

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, xcode7, bitcode

i'm building `llvm/clang 3.7` with bitcode support (`-fembed-bitcode`). Some modules can't be linked due to error:

> ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES)
>   cannot be used together clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Full error output:

> Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/BugpointPasses.dylib cd
>   /Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/llvm_37_ios_any_build/tools/bugpoint-passes
>   && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
>   CMakeFiles/BugpointPasses.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /usr/bin/c++ 
>   -fembed-bitcode -Os -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=8.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
>   -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
>   -bundle -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -Wl,-dead_strip -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/llvm_37_ios_any_build/tools/bugpoint-passes/BugpointPasses.exports
>   -Wl,-flat_namespace -Wl,-undefined -Wl,suppress -o ../../lib/BugpointPasses.dylib
>   CMakeFiles/BugpointPasses.dir/TestPasses.cpp.o
>   -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../lib  ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) make[2]: *** [lib/BugpointPasses.dylib] Error 1 make[1]:
>   *** [tools/bugpoint-passes/CMakeFiles/BugpointPasses.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2

It seems that `-bundle` is added by CMake as i was not able to find it in CMakeLists.txt and `-bitcode_bundle` is added by SDK because of `-fembed-bitcode`.

How can i fix it? Any workaround (f.e. to switch off dylibs building since i don't need them)?

Comment: I'd recommend to ask at clang users mailing list: http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/cfe-users

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are not using Bundle loader in any of your projects:
[image: Bundle Loader setting]
and set match-O type to Executable instead of Bundle
[image: Match-O type setting]

Hope that helps, I had the same problem and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Enable Bitcode` build setting to `No` for your debug configuration:

[image: "Enable Bitcode" is "No" for debug]

If you don't see the `Enable Bitcode` option, make sure `BaseSDK` is set to either `iOS`, `tvOS`, or `watchOS`.