# SwiftUI Preview fails with linker errors

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I've trying to add a SwiftUI view to an existing UIKit + Storyboards based tvOS project. The *actual* build works fine and I can run in the simulator & see my SwiftUI view, but when I resume the SwiftUI preview I get 'Failed to build MyClass.swift' with the following diagnostics:

[image: SwiftUI preview build error]

I saw [this similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471809/ld-bundle-and-bitcode-bundle-cannot-be-used-together) regarding the `-bundle and -bitcode_bundle cannot be used together` error, but my configuration is already the way the answer suggests (setting the Mach-O type to Executable and ensuring no Bundle Loader is set).

There's also a warning about `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-appletvsimulator` not being found. That directory certainly does not exist, but nowhere in my project is `SharedFrameworks-appletvsimulator` referenced that I can find. Also, if I create a new SwiftUI project it doesn't complain about that.

The SwiftUI code is literally just a new "Hello World" SwiftUI file from the Xcode template - I haven't modified it at all.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on here or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was disabling the code coverage option:

Go to your scheme menu -> select edit scheme -> go to the "Test" section on the left side menu -> uncheck the Code Coverage mark

- I'm using Xcode 12.5
- iOS minimum target 13.4

There are diffrent reasons for the preview to fails and several posts about it , for example:
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629916/swiftui-canvas-wont-build/68911979#68911979)